# How to open the attachment in the same screen as an image preview in template (Odoo16)

Tags: templates, pdf, attachment, qweb, odoo-16

I want to open the attachment in the same screen as an image preview.

**Python code:**

```
attachment_ids = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', 'purchase_order_line_attachment_rel', string='Attachments',
                                      attachment=True, copy=False, ondelete="restrict")
                                      

'attachments': [(attachment_id.name, attachment_id.datas, attachment_id.id, attachment_id.mimetype) for attachment_id in
                                    order.attachment_ids],
```

**xml template code:**

```
<t t-foreach="t.attachments" t-as="attachment">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: -6px;">
        <t t-if="attachment">
            <a t-att-href="'/web/content/' + attachment[2] + '?download=true'">
            <div class="oe_attachment_embedded o_image"
                 title="attachment[0]"
                 data-mimetype="application/pdf"></div>
                <span t-esc="attachment[0]"/>
            </a>
        </t>
    </div>
</t>
```

Above code open attachment in new tab as download whereas i want to open the attachment in the same screen as an image preview.

I am using odoo v16

Thanks in advance